# SQL SERVER Counting one record for a day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a following query which counts the number of orders for last week for seven sites.
If there is no order for a given site in last week it display 0 rather than not displaying the site at all, hence the reason i am using the Case statement.
All well and good, the challenge is that for a given date lets say 21/04/2014 if there are more than one orders for the site, my query shoudl only condsider  one record
, so for site4 the count value is 4 but it should be 3, the reason its 4 is because on 21st of this week it got two order entries.
is there any way i could only add 1 site for given day if more than two orderdates are found for that date?
i was considering using min(orderdate), but sql gives me errors that i cannot use aggregate function in a subquery or aggregate function.

```
select  SITENAME
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as COMPLETED
from TABLE1 where CLIENT in ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7')
GROUP BY SITENAME
order by SITENAME
```

```
SITENAME...............COMPLETED

SITE1.....................0

SITE2.....................0

SITE3.....................0

SITE4.....................4 *(the count should be 3 if you only consider unique dates for that site)

SITE5.....................2

SITE6.....................3

SITE7.....................2
```

Comment: I think the sql keyword `distinct` may be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get distinct dates in an inner query and then run your query on top:

```
select SITENAME
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as COMPLETED
from 
( 
   SELECT DISTINCT SITENAME, OrderDate FROM TABLE1
   where CLIENT in ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7') 
) X
GROUP BY SITENAME
order by SITENAME
```

Note, there's not really a need to group by address now when I'm using `distinct` in the inner query.

Comment: i have amended the query actually address is address was replaced by sitename , i dont get any records when i run your query

Comment: I have updated my query too. Do you get any results from the inner query alone?

Answer (score 1):

A simple and readable way to do that would be using a CTE:

```
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Sitename, 
    DATEADD(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690) Date,
    ORDERDATE,
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE CLIENT in ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7')
)
select  SITENAME
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= Date Then 1 Else 0 End) as COMPLETED
from data 
GROUP BY SITENAME 
order by SITENAME
```

Comment: i have amended the query actually address is address was replaced by sitename , and same i dont get any records when i run your query

Comment: @GROVER_SYAAN Updated now as well, try again

Answer (score 1):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select SITENAME,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Case When OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd, -53690, getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
                           Then OrderDate
             End) as COMPLETED
from TABLE1
where CLIENT in ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7')
GROUP BY SITENAME
order by SITENAME;
```

This assumes that `OrderDate` has no time component on it.  If so, then you can replace `Then OrderDate` with `Then cast(OrderDate as Date)`.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure does NOT seem to be right, for example if `TABLE1` is a Order table, then you are doing a `Group By` on whole table.

A good way is to use the SITE's master table and then do a count query on filtered records, for example,

```
DECLARE @tblAddress table(AddressID varchar(50));
DECLARE @tblOrders table(OrderAddress varchar(50), OrderID varchar(10), OrderDate date);

INSERT INTO @tblAddress(AddressID)
    SELECT    'SITE1'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE2'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE3'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE4'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE5'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE6'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE7'


INSERT INTO @tblOrders(OrderAddress, OrderID, OrderDate)
    SELECT    'SITE4', 'SITE4-01', '21-Apr-2014'        -- Site-4, order count = 1
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE5', 'SITE5-01', '21-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE6', 'SITE6-01', '21-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE7', 'SITE7-01', '21-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE4', 'SITE4-02', '22-Apr-2014'        -- Site-4, order count = 2
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE5', 'SITE5-02', '22-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE5', 'SITE5-03', '22-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE6', 'SITE6-02', '22-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE7', 'SITE7-02', '22-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE4', 'SITE4-03', '23-Apr-2014'        -- Site-4, order count = 3
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE7', 'SITE7-03', '23-Apr-2014'
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE4', 'SITE4-04', '24-Apr-2014'        -- Site-4, order count = 4
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE4', 'SITE4-05', '24-Apr-2014'        -- Site-4, order count = 5
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE4', 'SITE4-06', '24-Apr-2014'        -- Site-4, order count = 6
    UNION
    SELECT    'SITE4', 'SITE4-07', '24-Apr-2014'        -- Site-4, order count = 7


SELECT    AddressID,
        (
        SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT O.OrderDate)
        FROM    @tblOrders AS O    
        WHERE    OrderAddress = A.AddressID
                -- put your order filtering here
        ) AS TotalOrders
FROM    @tblAddress AS A
```

Comment: its actually pulling a data from a view and the column names are dummy since i didnt want to disclose the actual fields, but i will also try your approach with the view thanks for sharing